# Imaging UEFI computers

Tags: bios, upgrade, uefi, norton-ghost, imaging

We are buying computers for a new building, but our current imaging software, Symantec Ghost Solution Suite 2.5, does not support imaging of UEFI computers.  I’m hesitant to dummy down 300-500 computers into legacy mode so I can manage them with Ghost, preferring rather to keep the computers using the newest technology; My thought is that at some point UEFI will be the required standard, and then I will have to go to each machine to re-enable UEFI and re-install Windows…

Am I fretting over a small thing, being better off just disabling UEFI and continuing using Ghost, or are the benefits of UEFI and staying on the cusp of technology worth pursuing another Imaging solution?
If I should pursue another solution; What are others using to image UEFI computers?

Thank you

Comment: We cannot make product suggestions but the software you want to use is popular and can be found easily.  ( it's not a norton product )

Comment: Ramhound, I did not mean to ask for product suggestions, rather I was interested in what others where using.

My apologies if that question is to close to the line; It was not my intention, and I can edit my OP if needed. 

I am more interested in the importance of UEFI, as my OP states :)

Comment: There are dozens of recently updated imaging programs that exist this sort of question already had answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Windows software specifically, so I can't suggest what to try, but consider this: It will probably take you a few hours to research and find a new backup solution -- maybe a few days (probably well under 100 hours) to thoroughly test a couple of options. How many hundreds of hours will it take to switch 300-500 computers from EFI-mode booting to BIOS-mode booting? And then perhaps back again in the future? It seems to me that doing the research to find a new backup program now is likely to save you a *lot* of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is a content-agnostic stream copier so you might want to use it or one of its frontends.

It's a Linux/Unix/GNU Core tool though, but I don't have much (good) experience with those Backup suites.